# Pentaho-spoon Specify mysql connection without database name (for Multiple database access)

Tags: mysql, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a scenario where I have two separate databases `olap` and `oltp`, in the input-table or scripting(mysql) I want to join tables from these two different databases.

I am not able to leave database column blank when creating a connection, so I can't access both database (and join tables).

One solution suggested in an answer is to put variables in kettle.properties. but I am not sure how can I access those variables inside SQL query( will syntax like this ${} work in SQL?)

Comment: You mean you have a Query that has access to 2 segregated databases and uses Join on the Query itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Choose one database name in the connection.
- In the Table input step:

  `SELECT
      table1.field1
  ,   table2.field2
  FROM [database1].[schema].table1
  INNER JOIN [database2].[schema].table2`
- If that doesn't work try having two table input ( one for each database ) make sure they are sorted on the column you'll use as a key in the JOIN and use a Merge Join step as shown here:
  [image: Example]